# What is the point of getting trophies in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

As far as I know the only actual benefits from trophies are:

- The top 3 clans top 10 players receive some gem bonuses when ever a season completes
- There is the "Sweet Victory!" achievement which you can complete by obtaining 75/750/1250 trophies.
- And then there is the League All-Star achievement that gives you some gems as you reach those higher level leagues (250 for Chrystal, 1000 for Master and 2000 for Champion)

So, unless your clan can seriously compete of a position amongst the top 3 clans, then you have no incentive to maintain a high trophy count. You may want to temporarily rise it to get some gems from an achievement, but only temporarily.

So am I missing something or what's the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the rewards you already mentioned, there is a bonus for every raid you win that is based on what league you're in.  It's usually small, but it can make a difference.

There's also the same reason there are leaderboards in any game - to see how you stack up against other players!

There is a downside to having many trophies, and that's that trophy count is an important factor in matchmaking.  Thus, if you have many trophies you're going to get raided often by high level players, and you're likely to get matched up against hard opponents.

Many players that I've seen will try to maintain or lower their trophy count in order to find easier players to raid.  You've probably seen players dropping trophies in this manner - usually, they will deploy a single troop against you, or they'll put out and immediate recall their hero units.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention about the loot bonus, but it's ridiculously minuscule. E.g. on Gold I you get 13k+13k. That's nothing, when a good successful raid can give you hundreds of thousands of resources (and if your aiming for 3 star victory so does your army). So if your trying to max your income and "do most damage" to your opponents it's best to try and not win games (and give free shields), but just steal as much resources as possible, with as cheap units as possible. Then you do need to bother to intentionally drop your trophy count later on?

Comment: And the leader board... IMHO, more important indicators of your level or status in the game is TH lvl as wells as other buildings and the thing you can brag with is how awesome loots you've managed to get. Nobody cares how much trophies you have or how high are you in your league.

Comment: @TimoLehto, I didn't say you would care about the reasons, I just listed them :)  As with most games like this, the goals are whatever you make them.  Are trophies a good goal to set?  It seems for you, (and probably a lot of people agree) the answer is no.

Comment: It also needs to be mentioned that managing your trophy count is how you find more loot as you go up in TH level. For example in the 1000-1200 trophy range, you are going to find less dark elixer to loot than in the 1600-2000 trophy range. Plus, if you are say a TH9 or TH10 , that is even further exaggerated because less loot is available when attacking lower TH bases.

Answer (score 1):

Well, many have the goal to become a top player. Early on however, it doesn't matter having 2K trophies just to be the best in your clan or whatever, I'd rather have 1K trophies and build my base during 6 months, and then try and go for 4K+ trophies. Long term thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Until version 7.1.1 only the topmost players in your clan participated in a war e.g. if a 18 members clan fought in a 15 vs 15 war. If your trophy count was low you did not get to fight in the clan war.

As of version 7.1.1 from 24th February 2015 the clan leader can manually select who is going to participate when starting clan war search. Additionally members can toggle in their profile whether they would like to participate.
So currently the trophy count just defines the ordering in the war zone. As a result a player with a strong war base can be ranked below a player with a weaker one which might influence the clan XP gained from successfully attacking that base.

Answer (score 1):

The bonuses would be the most important reason to maintain high trophy count. The loot bonus is already mentioned in a comment.

Now we also have the star bonus, which is a more important factor.  Although you only get it for each 5 stars you gain in multiplayer battle, it is quite substantial amount. Also you will get dark elixir starting at lower leagues than you get with the normal loot bonus.

Comment: I don't play anymore; I got bored of this game, but could you elaborate on the importance of the start bonus stuff and why is such a big deal?

Answer (score 0):

Well been playing for a while, lvl 99, with lvl 9 th and lvl 7 walls (regret upgrading the walls past pink to purple). Have most buildings upgraded to the max for th9 ( still have one upgrade to go on mortars, wizard towers, and cannons. Hence why I regret doing walls.) All elixir upgrades except lvl 6 flying bombers are complete...

I can say with all honesty I still haven't figured out what the point of having trophies is... I rarely fight and only participate in clan wars I know are 100% wins. Why? Because regardless of the build I choose to use... I end up spending too much reasources fighting. Ie: lvl5 hog riders will be almost 4k dark elixir so screw that because finding someone with 500,000 resources to equalize that isn't going to happen. And if I build just elixir units and spells, I'll still run about 230k so I end up searching for a good match for 10+min and will make maybe 100k... If I get lucky. I just collect my resources now for the most part... Don't see any other point really.

Comment: Clan wars, unlike other modes of play is a truer indication of strength of the clan. Since matchmaking finds a clan of similar strength based on troops/buildings etc, theoretically it's a fair matchup. How many clan war wins your clan has, is a better indication of actual skills than trophy count. Some do get a sense of actual achievement by using strategy to defeat a more powerful opponent - who might have gemmed or farmed his way to high level troops and defenses, but doesn't have war skills to match.

Comment: Well, I join the Clan Wars more because I enjoy the competition in battle, more than gaining resources. Also to help the clan gaining more XP for getting more perks.

Answer (score 0):

In Clash of Clans, controlling your trophies is very important because:

1. To rank on the leader boards: Your Clan, Top Clans, Top Players, My Leagues,…
2. To stay at the most relative league for you to farm.
3. To join a Clan (it requires a minimum trophies to join).